# CSS float property not working, how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css

I made a div and used float:right in i but the float property is not working. 
*Update: I found out that the reason the code isn't working is because of the display: inline-block that keeps the position of the div. How do I override the display?

```
#about{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #about-title{
        text-align:center;
        padding:15px;
        color:white;
        background:#774C60;
        float:right;
    }
```

Comment: if `#about-title` is child of `#about`, then if you set a width to `#about` it will work. Posting your HTML will help you in having better answers

Comment: use `!important` front of overriding property in css

Answer (score 0):

Use it :

```
#about{
    display:block;
}
```

or

```
#about{
    width:100%;
}
```